# Calling Restful api function from AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I have Restful API service in asp.net, which provides code for JavaScript to use, i need to use its functions in angular.
I am posting code here which has RestAPI function and it includes calls to data and it should return JSON data to calling function i believe. please if anybody familiar with the solution your response will be highly appreciated. 
Thank-you.

```
function RestAPI(){ self = this; }
RestAPI.prototype = {
    self: null,
    urlString: "http://exclusiveautosales.azurewebsites.net/ExclusiveAutoSales_Handler.ashx",
    GetFiltersMain:function(successFunction,failFunction,token) {
        var data = { 'interface': 'RestAPI', 'method': 'GetFiltersMain', 'parameters': {}, 'token': token };
        var jsonData = dojo.toJson(data);
        var xhrArgs = {
            url: self.urlString,
            handleAs: 'json',
            postData: jsonData,
            load: successFunction,
            error: failFunction };
        var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
    },
    GetMakeModelPrice:function(make_id,model_id,min_price,max_price,successFunction,failFunction,token) {
        var data = { 'interface': 'RestAPI', 'method': 'GetMakeModelPrice', 'parameters': {'make_id':make_id,'model_id':model_id,'min_price':min_price,'max_price':max_price}, 'token': token };

        var jsonData = dojo.toJson(data);
        var xhrArgs = {
            url: self.urlString,
            handleAs: 'json',
            postData: jsonData,
            load: successFunction,
            error: failFunction };
        var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
    },
    GetSearchResult:function(search_q,make_id,model_id,year_id,engine_id,color_id,body_id,transmission_id,fueltype_id,subfeature_id,minPrice,maxPrice,successFunction,failFunction,token) {
        var data = { 'interface': 'RestAPI', 'method': 'GetSearchResult', 'parameters': {'search_q':search_q,'make_id':make_id,'model_id':model_id,'year_id':year_id,'engine_id':engine_id,'color_id':color_id,'body_id':body_id,'transmission_id':transmission_id,'fueltype_id':fueltype_id,'subfeature_id':subfeature_id,'minPrice':minPrice,'maxPrice':maxPrice}, 'token': token };

        var jsonData = dojo.toJson(data);
        var xhrArgs = {
            url: self.urlString,
            handleAs: 'json',
            postData: jsonData,
            load: successFunction,
            error: failFunction };
        var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
    }
};
```

Comment: With all due respect - this is not a RESTful API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help you to solve [ASP.NET Web Service In AngularJS Using $HTTP](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consuming-asp-net-web-service-in-angularjs-using-http/)

user `$http` service for  Restful

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
       app .controller('RestAPI',function($scope, $http) {                    
                $http({
                    method : "GET",
                    url : "http://exclusiveautosales.azurewebsites.net/ExclusiveAutoSales_Handler.ashx",
                    data :{ 'interface': 'RestAPI', 'method': 'GetFiltersMain', 'parameters': {}, 'token': token }
                }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                    $scope.jsonData = response.data;
                }, function myError(response) {
                    $scope.jsonData = response;
                });
            });
```

Comment: it says token is not defined, can you please check it one more time?